# How to fix python import error cannot import name

Tags: python, importerror

I'm facing a problem related to the packages in the code. I'm new to coding in python. I saved files in this structure:

```
Directory structure for project folder:

`  utils(subfolder)
   main.py`    



Directory structure for utils:
settings.py
__init__.py
button.py
```

I'll be attaching the python codes

```
`#main.py
import os
import sys

utils_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'utils')
sys.path.append(utils_path)

from utils.button import Button
import pygame

WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Drawing Program")


def init_grid(rows, cols, color):
    grid = []

    for i in range(rows):
        grid.append([])
        for _ in range(cols):
            grid[i].append(color)

    return grid


def draw_grid(win, grid):
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, pixel in enumerate(row):
            pygame.draw.rect(win, pixel, (j * PIXEL_SIZE, i *
                                          PIXEL_SIZE, PIXEL_SIZE, PIXEL_SIZE))

    if DRAW_GRID_LINES:
        for i in range(ROWS + 1):
            pygame.draw.line(win, BLACK, (0, i * PIXEL_SIZE),
                             (WIDTH, i * PIXEL_SIZE))

        for i in range(COLS + 1):
            pygame.draw.line(win, BLACK, (i * PIXEL_SIZE, 0),
                             (i * PIXEL_SIZE, HEIGHT - TOOLBAR_HEIGHT))


def draw(win, grid, buttons):
    win.fill(BG_COLOR)
    draw_grid(win, grid)

    for button in buttons:
        button.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()


def get_row_col_from_pos(pos):
    x, y = pos
    row = y // PIXEL_SIZE
    col = x // PIXEL_SIZE

    if row >= ROWS:
        raise IndexError

    return row, col


run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
grid = init_grid(ROWS, COLS, BG_COLOR)
drawing_color = BLACK

button_y = HEIGHT - TOOLBAR_HEIGHT/2 - 25
buttons = [
    Button(10, button_y, 50, 50, BLACK),
    Button(70, button_y, 50, 50, RED),
    Button(130, button_y, 50, 50, GREEN),
    Button(190, button_y, 50, 50, BLUE),
    Button(250, button_y, 50, 50, WHITE, "Erase", BLACK),
    Button(310, button_y, 50, 50, WHITE, "Clear", BLACK)
]

while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            try:
                row, col = get_row_col_from_pos(pos)
                grid[row][col] = drawing_color
            except IndexError:
                for button in buttons:
                    if not button.clicked(pos):
                        continue

                    drawing_color = button.color
                    if button.text == "Clear":
                        grid = init_grid(ROWS, COLS, BG_COLOR)
                        drawing_color = BLACK

    draw(WIN, grid, buttons)

pygame.quit()

#settings.py
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 0)
GREEN = (0, 0, 255)

FPS = 240

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 600, 700

ROWS = COLS = 100

TOOLBAR_HEIGHT = HEIGHT - WIDTH

PIXEL_SIZE = WIDTH // COLS

BG_COLOR = WHITE

DRAW_GRID_LINES = True


def get_font(size):
    return pygame.font.SysFont("comicsans", size)
```

#button.py

```
from .settings import *


class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, text=None, text_color=BLACK):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
        self.text_color = text_color

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(
            win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(
            win, BLACK, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 2)
        if self.text:
            button_font = get_font(22)
            text_surface = button_font.render(self.text, 1, self.text_color)
            win.blit(text_surface, (self.x + self.width /
                                    2 - text_surface.get_width()/2, self.y + self.height/2 - text_surface.get_height()/2))

    def clicked(self, pos):
        x, y = pos

        if not (x >= self.x and x <= self.x + self.width):
            return False
        if not (y >= self.y and y <= self.y + self.height):
            return False

        return True


#init.py
`from .settings import *

from .button import Button

import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.font.init()
```

`

Python compiler keeps giving me this error :

```
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python_work\Hackathon\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils.button import Button
  File "c:\python_work\Hackathon\utils\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .button import Button
ImportError: cannot import name 'Button' from 'utils.button' (c:\python_work\Hackathon\utils\button.py)
```

`

I have tried different ways to resolve the error I was suggested to modify my PYTHONPATH and also remove utils from the import Button statement in the main.py file

```
`from button import Button`
```

But the compiler kept throwing the ImportError. I'm not able to understand how I can proceed further with this. Is it a better alternative to write the code in a single file which may get rid of the error. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The exception mentions the `__init__.py` file you have in `utils`. What's the contents of that file? You shouldn't need to do any `sys.path` munging to get that directory structure to work correctly.

Comment: In utils I have  the following files 1)setting.py  2) __init__.py 3) button.py. In the __init__.py file I'll be importing everything from my settings.py file